# Creating a subset of a table into a new table with top 5 rows from old table.

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is what I came up with buy keep getting syntax error :

The old table name is **Physician** and
the new table name is **Physician1**

`CREATE TABLE Physician1 AS 
 SELECT TOP 5 
 FROM Physician;`

Errors Include:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'
>
> > Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax is not valid.

This would work:

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
INTO Physician1
FROM Physician
```